# how can i optimise following code for producer consumer problem

Tags: java, concurrency, producer-consumer

I am having 1 producer and 2 (multiple) consumers.

The following code works fine(free from race conditions IMO) but the problem is whenever the buffer is empty,each consumer is executing an infinite loop, which is just wait of resources.

How can i optimise it? I am thinking of using something like notifying consumer in case anything is added to buffer but having problem in implementation.

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Assembly assembly = new Assembly(new ArrayList<>(), new ReentrantLock(true));

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        assembly.consume();
      }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        assembly.produce();
      }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        assembly.consume();
      }
    }).start();
  }
}

class Assembly {

  List<Integer> buffer;
  Lock bufferLock;

  public Assembly(List<Integer> buffer, Lock bufferLock) {
    this.buffer = buffer;
    this.bufferLock = bufferLock;
  }

  public void produce() {
    Integer[] nums = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 99};
    Random random = new Random();
    for (Integer num : nums) {
      try {
        bufferLock.lock();
        buffer.add(num);
        if (num != 99) {
          System.out.println("Added: " + num);
        }
      } finally {
        bufferLock.unlock();
        try {
          Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public void consume() {
    while (true) {
      try {
        bufferLock.lock();
        if (buffer.isEmpty()) {
          **IS SOME OPTIMISATION POSSIBLE HERE?**
          continue;
        }
        if (buffer.get(0).equals(99)) {
          break;
        }
        System.out.println(
            "Removed: " + buffer.remove(0) + " by " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
      } finally {
        bufferLock.unlock();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Drop the `List` and use one of the blocking queues such as `LinkedBlockingQueue` or `ArrayBlockingQueue`. And in these cases it's always good to make a defensive copy of whatever collection you receive as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Semaphore` to add/remove available elements

```
public class ProducerConsumer {
    List<Integer> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
    Semaphore available = new Semaphore(0);

    public static void main(String... args) {
        ProducerConsumer pc = new ProducerConsumer();
        new Thread(pc::consume).start();
        new Thread(pc::produce).start();
        new Thread(pc::consume).start();
    }

    public void produce() {
        Integer[] nums = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 99};
        Random random = new Random();
        for (Integer num : nums) {
            try {
                synchronized (buffer) {
                    buffer.add(num);
                }
                available.release();
                System.out.println("Added: " + num);
            } finally {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void consume() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                available.acquire();
                synchronized (buffer) {
                    if (buffer.get(0).equals(99)) {
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println(
                            "Removed: " + buffer.remove(0) + " by " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

your (consumer) threads will be blocked until a new item is available.

With output

```
Added: 1
Removed: 1 by Thread-0
Added: 2
Removed: 2 by Thread-2
Added: 3
Removed: 3 by Thread-0
...
```

Comment: i am learning java concurrency, would definitely be checking semaphores, but can it be achieved by using await() and signal()?

Comment: re await & signal.   You don't want to signal all consumers, you only want one to actually wake up.  The producer does not currently know which consumers are available.  So you'll need a queue of waiting consumers, and the consumer will have to enqueue itself.  By this point you've more-or-less implemented a semaphore.

Comment: @RajatAggarwal you could use await and signal raising some event from producer then, some middleware (called something like _"task broker"_) `signal` the next free consumer (probably using a priority queue), you could use this approach instead simply `Semaphore` when you need a fine control over what consumer do what task, e.g. maybe one consumer is cheaper than others, faster, and so, ...

Comment: @Holger right, the example only show how to not check for availability, any other struct must be checked for thread safe, but the best way depends of producer/consumer definition (in this case a simple `synchronized (buffer) {` works but may be not sufficient). I've update anyway. Note: I have assumed that he is interested in knowing how to optimize *that line* not convert his code to `ArrayBlockingQueue`.

Comment: @Holger please explain how it is broken? Only one thread can have lock at a time.

Comment: @RajatAggarwal without `synchronized (buffer)` is broken.

Comment: @RajatAggarwal the answer has been updated since I wrote that comment. So ignore the first part of my comment. Only the second part might be interesting for you, i.e. that the source code of `ArrayBlockingQueue` contains an example of how to solve such a problem using a `ReentrantLock` and `await()` and `signal()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) instead of trying to roll your own. The consumers will wait until an 'item' is available, and only one will wake up to get the item.

The classic [producer-consumer solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem#Using_semaphores) uses two semaphores, the 'other' one being used by the producer to wait until a 'free slot' is available.  Without that, the producer can outrun the ability of consumers to keep up.  Your program looks like it has a small finite limit on production, so that might not apply here.